# Google chart with average rating

Tags: charts, datatable

i need to visualize the google chart with the average rating made for a products based on the 1 week, 2 Months, 4 Months, 8 Months and 12 Months, so i have tried to visualize it with the google visualization tool, so i got the following code there

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Duration', 'rating'],
          ['1 week',  1],
          ['2 Months',  2],
          ['4 Months',  3],
          ['8 Months',  4],
          ['1 Year',  5],

        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data,
                 {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
                  width:600, height:400,
                  hAxis: {title: "Year"}}
            );
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here it displaying the output as [image]

​ i need the y axis must be 1 to 5 and in the x axis must have the average rating based on the time frame, is this is possible? what i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of the question...

> ...y axis must be 1 to 5...

... you have to format the y axis, which isn't in your code yet.

Change your call to `google.visualization.ColumnChart` to

```
new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('visualization')).draw(
        data, {
            title:  "Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:  600,         
            height: 400,
            hAxis: {
                title: "Year"
            },
        vAxis: {                  <- new code from here...
            minValue:0, 
            format:'#',
            gridlines:{
                count:6
            }
        }
    }
);
```

This should format the axis according to your description.

The 2nd part of your question,

> ...the x axis must have the average rating based on the time frame...

is not yet clear to me. Please add some more detail to it, p.e. how / what kind of data do you want where.

Comment: @Bjoem , how i can implement your above code into mycode? if i use `google.visualization.ColumnChart` instead of it, it doesn't show to me, maybe it cause the error

Comment: about "the x axis must have the average rating based on the time frame." is input am having the average rating for the 1 week, 2Month and so on

Comment: @kani Just add the block from `vAxis ... ` into your `google.visualization.ColumnChart` call. If it doesn't show, you possibly have a jscript error in there. Maybe just replace the six lines of code beneath `//create and draw...` with my example, this should do the job. Please describe your other question while using some example data to clarify.